# How to remove Symfony asset leading slash?

Tags: symfony, twig, assets

To use standalone twig with standalone asset I use this code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\PackageInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\AssetExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Package;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\PathPackage;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\UrlPackage;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\EmptyVersionStrategy;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Context\RequestStackContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

$versionStrategy = new EmptyVersionStrategy();
$namedPackages = array(
    'css' => new PathPackage('twig/css', $versionStrategy, new RequestStackContext(new RequestStack())),
);
$defaultPackage = new Package($versionStrategy);
$packages = new Packages($defaultPackage, $namedPackages);
$twig->addExtension(new AssetExtension($packages));
```

It works fine, I use {{ asset () }} function but it adds a leading / in path like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/twig/css/mystyles.css">
```

that causes css file not found and not loaded. Without leading / it works fine.
How to fix it?
I am using twig-bridge to have asset in my twig as I am using both of them standalone.